# htaccess rewrite rule: $_GET not submitting, submitting invalid data

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying for days now to get something working in my htaccess file. I've made a search and i'm trying to use RewriteRule but for some reason its not working, sometimes it sends empty $_GET data sometimes its sends values with .php in it for some reason. Its driving me crazy.

These are the rules, htacces works on my server since all the other rewrite rules work fine.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4&category=$5&page=$6&order=$7&results=$8&kind=$9 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4&category=$5&page=$6&order=$7&results=$8 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4&category=$5&page=$6&order=$7 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4&category=$5&page=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4&category=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3&game=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2&data=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/ /search.php [L]
```

Anyone finds the problem in this lines or know what this problem causes? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 changes:

1. Change all the `([^/]*)` to `([^/]+)` to make sure it doesn't match empty string
2. Add `Options -MultiViews` line on top of your .htaccess to turn off content negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to put on your .htaccess file this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?values=$1 [QSA]
```

in your search.php file put this

```
if (isset($_GET['values']))
{
    $GET = explode("/",$_GET['values']);
    $query = $GET[0];
    $type = $GET[1];
    $data = $GET[2];
    $game = $GET[3];
    $category = $GET[4];
    $page = $GET[5];
    $order = $GET[6];
    $results = $GET[7];
    $kind = $GET[8];
}
```

But you need also to test every `$GET[..]` if `isset`

Answer (score 0):

This is insane!
You should use a much more lean htaccess and do the "controller" stuff with PHP!

Here is an example:

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So the index.php is called on every request. Here you can parse your URL.

**index.php**

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);

if($url[0] == 'search'){
    $file = 'search.php'
    if (file_exists($file)) {
      // Here all your former GET-Variables can be accessed through the array $url
      // e.g. $_GET["query"] equals $url[1];
      $search['query'] = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : '';
      $search['type']  = isset($url[2]) ? $url[2] : '';
      // etc.

      require $file;
    } 
}
```